# Select 1 record in every 'x' records in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to select 1 record out of every 50 records in bigquery. I have a very large table and can't really do an `order by rand()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT (rnd) FROM (
  SELECT rand() rnd, *
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table` 
)
WHERE rnd < 0.02
```